# read.table() in R did not read all the columns

Tags: r, read.table

I know there are already some related answers but my file is more complex to handle, and I appreciate your help!

To read all columns of following .txt file:

```
 chr1 123456 A G "exonic" "geneA" "nonsynonymous SNV" "CNTN5:NM_175566:exon11:c.A1366G:p.I456V,CNTN5:NM_001243270:exon13:c.A1588G:p.I530V" "0.1004" 10.68 . . 0.2023 0.3004 2.091
 chr2 345678 A C "intronic" "geneB" . . 0.06 12.04 . . 0.5046 0.1004 8.046
```

the tricky thing is that the txt file has columns with values either quoted with "" or with no "" character

when I tried

```
d <- read.table("my.txt",header = F)
```

it only read 10 columns, while the original file has 15 columns,

I checked the original file, exactly the last five columns were missed during the reading process

in this example, the missing columns are

```
. . 0.2023 0.3004 2.091
. . 0.5046 0.1004 8.046
```

then I tried

```
d2 <- read.table("my.txt",quote = "",header = F)
```

then it warned "line 1 did not have 15 elements

I would like to have all the data (rows and columns) correctly read, how should I do to achieve that goal?

Thanks! I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error with the two lines of your code. On my R session, the file open with 15 columns using `read.table("mytxt.txt",header = F)`

Comment: @dc37 yes, you are right, I just checked numbers of columns for each row, more than 10000 lines have missing columns, I created empty columns for those lines and correctly read all the columns, finally! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to manually add columns. While reading try the `fill=TRUE` option :

```
read.table("mytxt.txt",header=FALSE,fill=TRUE)
```